# Redshift DEFAULT GETDATE() column resulting in unmatched number of columns error

Tags: amazon-redshift

EDIT: this does work, the problem was I had inconsistent column names. But, it doesn't work for parquet files. Once I fixed the column names, I got the error:

```
     Column mapping option argument is not supported for PARQUET based COPY
```

I'm using the GETDATE() function to create a column for the current date. This is in my CREATE TABLE command as the last column:

```
      sql = '''CREATE TABLE if not exists auto_content.DM_CONTENT 
 (C_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 M_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
 A_ID CHAR(36),
 A_NAME VARCHAR(32),
 TITLE VARCHAR(255),
 E_ID VARCHAR(255),
 START_DT TIMESTAMP,
 END_DT TIMESTAMP,
 DURATION_MS DOUBLE PRECISION,
 INTERACTION_TYPE VARCHAR(32),
 NUM_CHAN SMALLINT NOT NULL,
 UPLOAD_VERSION VARCHAR(64),
 M_CONTENT_TYPE VARCHAR(32),
 T_STATUS VARCHAR(32),
 NUM_WORDS DOUBLE PRECISION,
 METADATA_JSON VARCHAR(256),
 CREATED_DT TIMESTAMP,
 FINISHED_DT TIMESTAMP,
 LOAD_DT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT GETDATE()
    )
 DISTSTYLE KEY
 DISTKEY (C_ID)'''
```

Then, I'm using the COPY command to populate the table with files in s3. In looking at the AWS  [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-load-data-from-a-file-with-default-values) it seems the procedure is to include the 18 column names from the s3 file as values in the command, and, so I created it like so:

```
    sql = "COPY my_schema.my_table(col1,col2) FROM 's3://bucket/folder/file.parquet' ACCESS_KEY_ID 'zz' SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 'zz' FORMAT AS PARQUET;"
```

but this is not working and I get the error

```
    "Unmatched number of columns between table and file"
```

What is the correct way to use the COPY command so that the default column already created in the Table gets populated? Or am I doing this procedure in the wrong order?

Comment: Please share the entire create table command, and sample data from your file. This should work, and redshift should load the default.

Comment: How many columns of data are in your parquet file? 2?

Comment: there are 18 columns in the parquet file.

Comment: in taking a look at my column names i see they don't all match up exactly with the ones in the create table command. i'm guessing this may be the actual issue.

Comment: Now that i've fixed my column names, I get the error: " Column mapping option argument is not supported for PARQUET based COPY". So i'll need to find a workaround for this.